# Converting a linreg V1 Function to V5 (Tradingview - Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I tried to convert pine v1 linreg function to v3 (and afterwards convert it automatically to V5) but I kept getting this error:

> syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

This is the V1 code

```
val = linreg(source  -  avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, lengthKC)),sma(close,lengthKC)), 
            lengthKC,0)
```

So I looked it up in the pine script language reference and the function should look like this:

> linreg(source, length, offset) → series

If I'm correct, the source should be this:

> source  -  avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, lengthKC)),

Length:

> sma(close,lengthKC)),

And Offset:

> lengthKC,0)

So I wrote it like this in V3:

`val = linreg((source  -  avg(highest(high, lengthKC)), avg(lowest(low, lengthKC))), (avg(sma(close,lengthKC))), (lengthKC,0))`

But it keeps telling me

> mismatched input ',' expecting ')'

I played around with some other solutions but couldnt figure out how to solve the problem.

EDIT:
This is the full code:

````
study(shorttitle = "SQZMOM_LB", title="Squeeze Momentum Indicator [LazyBear]", overlay=false)

length = input(20, title="BB Length")
mult = input(2.0,title="BB MultFactor")
lengthKC=input(20, title="KC Length")
multKC = input(1.5, title="KC MultFactor")

useTrueRange = input(true, title="Use TrueRange (KC)", type=bool)

// Calculate BB
source = close
basis = sma(source, length)
dev = multKC * stdev(source, length)
upperBB = basis + dev
lowerBB = basis - dev

// Calculate KC
ma = sma(source, lengthKC)
range = useTrueRange ? tr : (high - low)
rangema = sma(range, lengthKC)
upperKC = ma + rangema * multKC
lowerKC = ma - rangema * multKC

sqzOn  = (lowerBB > lowerKC) and (upperBB < upperKC)
sqzOff = (lowerBB < lowerKC) and (upperBB > upperKC)
noSqz  = (sqzOn == false) and (sqzOff == false)

val = linreg((source  -  avg(highest(high, lengthKC)), avg(lowest(low, lengthKC))), (avg(sma(close,lengthKC))), (lengthKC,0))

bcolor = iff( val > 0, 
            iff( val > nz(val[1]), lime, green),
            iff( val < nz(val[1]), red, maroon))
scolor = noSqz ? blue : sqzOn ? black : gray 
plot(val, color=bcolor, style=histogram, linewidth=4)
plot(0, color=scolor, style=cross, linewidth=2)```
````

Comment: Can you share the full code of the original indicator?

Comment: Sure - I already updated it. Thanks again!

Comment: This code does not compile. I searched for it in the library and the code is a little different at that line. `val = linreg(source - avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, lengthKC)),sma(close,lengthKC)), lengthKC,0)`

Comment: That solved the problem - thank you very much! Where did you search for it exactly? Because I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code is slightly different.

The definition of `val` is as below:

```
val = linreg(source - avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, lengthKC)),sma(close,lengthKC)), lengthKC,0)
```

If you search for *Squeeze Momentum Indicator [LazyBear]* in the indicator list, you can find the indicator.

[image]